# prove that $ E = \{(x,y) \in E_2 | x \in E_1 \} =E_2 \cap(E_1 \times \Bbb{R^n}) \in \Bbb{R^{m+n}}$ have jordan mesuare

Tags: calculus, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $ E_1 \in \Bbb{R^m}$ and $E_2 \in \Bbb{R^{m+n}} $

be two groups with jordan mesuare.

prove that $ E = \{(x,y) \in E_2 | x \in E_1 \} =E_2 \cap(E_1 \times \Bbb{R^n}) \in \Bbb{R^{m+n}}$ also have jordan mesuare

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you ask if $E$ is Jordan measurable provided both $E_1$ and $E_2$ are Jordan measurable. Since the set $E_2$ is Jordan measurable, it is bounded. Therefore there exists a number $N$ such that $E_2\subset [-N,N]^{m+n}$. Then $E_2\cap E_1\times\Bbb {R}^n= E_2\cap (E_1\times[-N,N]^n)$.  The measurability of a set $E_1\times [-N,N]^n$ follows almost directly from the definition of Jordan measure $m$. The intersection $E=E_2\cap (E_1\times [-N,N]^n)$ is Jordan measurable as an intersection of two Jordan measurable sets.

Comment: can you please explain why $E_1 \times \Bbb{R^n}$ is measurable? and why if $ n \gt 1$ then $m( E_1 \times \Bbb{R^n}) = 0$

Comment: @DanielKatzan Oops, I misread $E_1\times\Bbb R^n$ as $E_1\times\Bbb\{0\}$. Sorry. I corrected the answer.